# ListView does not get initialized in AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have an application that brings me the data of sqlite and presents them in a listview that is in a fragment, I use an asynctask to do this, when I do debug there is no error, when I run the application I boot

**java.lang.NullPointerException error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter (android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference**.

Why does this happen?

> **Fragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frm_lst_cobertura, container, false);
}
```

> **AsyncTask**

```
public class BckListCobertura extends AsyncTask<String, Fila_Lista_cobertura, String> {
ActivityMenu activity;
ListView listViewCobertura;

public BckListCobertura(ActivityMenu activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.delegate = activity;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
fila_lista_cobertura_adapter = new Fila_Lista_cobertura_adapter(activity, R.layout.row_lst_cobertura, colorlista);
        listViewCobertura = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.lstvCobertura);
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listViewCobertura.setAdapter(fila_lista_cobertura_adapter);
delegate.processFinishListCobertura(result);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do the UI part in doInBackground method.You need to find the id in onCreateView method and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are initializing the `ListView`, which is a UI component, in a thread that is not the **UI Thread**.

In Android, everything related to the UI, must be done in the main thread.

It is good practice to initialize each `Activity`'s own component in their `onCreate()` method, or, in case your component is in a `Fragment`, in its `onCreateView()` method.

If you really do want to initialize the elements inside your `AsyncTask`, you can override the `onPreExecute()` method which, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute()), is executed in the main thread.

Still, I don't know how much of a good practice is that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply, I am new to this android, tell me how I would initialize the listview on the oncreate and be able to add the data to the adapter from the asynctask?

Comment: I was able to solve it, initialize the listview in the onPostExecute

Comment: Glad to see you did it by yourself! Mark the answer as correct if you believe it helped you solve your question. Otherwise post your own solution and accept it, so future readers will be helped as well. Welcome to SO